# jQuery roundabout featured item with different dimensions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery Roundabout](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout) plugin to create a carousel. I have a need to allow the currently selected item - to which Roundabout applies a class of "roundabout-in-focus" - to be more of a "featured" item. So it would need to have a bigger width, specifically, which does not seem to be supported by the plugin. If I add it to the CSS for that class, it is ignored when the plugin sets its own styles.

I know I can just use jQuery to set the width() after the roundabout loads, but it does not switch as you click through the items.

Any thoughts on how I could do this? Ideally I could set the width of the current item and have it be positioned as it should be within the carousel's limits, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Thanks